# Javascript development: When do you prefer sync over async?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I was reading an MDN [article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests), and it states that almost always async is a better approach than making synchronous calls from the browser to your back end. It then goes on to say "In rare cases, the use of a synchronous method is preferable to an asynchronous one." I was wondering what are some use-cases when we would prefer making synchronous requests ?

Comment: Only time I've ever wanted to utilize a synchronous op is when the application absolutely positively should not DO ANYTHING until that op is finished. That said, programming async ops in that fashion is completely possible, and definitely preferred since it won't just lock the browser on your users.

Comment: For example, you want to open the tab after a user has clicked on the button, but only if a positive response has come from the server. You can't do it with the asynchronous request because browser will count it as not user initiated action, and will block tab from opening. But you can do this with synchronous request

Answer (score 3):

Synchronous AJAX requests completely block the UI (the same way that, for example, a native alert box does). The JavaScript concurrency model is based on leveraging asynchronous operations. I can't think of a single use-case where a synchronous request would have benefits over an async one.

As far as stylistic concerns, like "waterfalls" of callbacks, etc., these can all be managed  fairly easily through different means. For example, various Promise libraries, or native ES6 features like "coroutines" (generators that deal with Promises) or even just native ES6 promises.

I think if you're running into a situation where you feel the need to call a synchronous request, then you need to step back and re-think the architecture of your application (not talking about you specifically, but just in general).

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript the rule is async first! Only in case that is not possible go for synchronous !!